# PASE for i on IBM i 7.5: fstatat, openat return -1 w/ errno == EINVAL

Tags: c

I have a library that uses `fstatat` to open a directory, and then stat a path relative to that directory using code resembling the following:

```c
int fd = open("/some/directory", O_DIRECTORY);
if (-1 == fd) {
   // handle error
   return;
}

struct stat st = {0};
if (-1 == fstatat(fd, "./file_in_dir", &st, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW)) {
    // handle error
}

close(fd);
```

I am able to enumerate the contents of the directory using `fdopendir` / `readdir`, so I know I have a valid directory file descriptor. Regardless, no matter what I try, I *always* get a -1 return value from `fstatat` (and `openat`) with errno == `EINVAL` (22).

According to the IBM [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.3?topic=s-stat-fstat-lstat-statx-fstatx-statxat-fstatat-fullstat-ffullstat-stat64-fstat64-lstat64-stat64x-fstat64x-lstat64x-stat64xat-subroutine), `fstatat` can result in `EINVAL` when the *flags are invalid*. Having discovered this, I grepped the system headers for `AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW` and found the following:

```c
#if (_XOPEN_SOURCE >= 700) || defined(_KERNEL)
#define AT_FDCWD                (-2)    /* Use the current working
                                         * directory to determine the
                                         * beginning of relative file
                                         * paths.                       */
#define AT_EACCESS              1       /* Check access using effective
                                         * user and group ID.           */
#define AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW     1       /* Do not follow symbolic links */
#define AT_SYMLINK_FOLLOW       2       /* Follow symbolic links        */
#define AT_REMOVEDIR            1       /* Remove the directory entry
                                         * specified by fd and path as
                                         * a directory, not a normal
                                         * file.                        */
#endif
```

Now, I may be off-base, but doesn't this seem like no matter what value you pass for flags, it is invalid because `AT_REMOVEDIR` is the same value as `AT_EACCESS` and `AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW`?

The most interesting thing is that if and only if I pass `AT_FDCWD` for the file descriptor, *it successfully stats the file*.

I have tried every permutation of flags, trailing slashes, no trailing slashes, dot-slash prefix, no dot-slash prefix, etc. This code works correctly on every single platform we've encountered to date, and that is not an insignificant number.

I have been trying to figure this out for many hours now, so I am resorting to asking here. Anyone out there have a clue?

Comment: This might be an IBM thing. I've got a PC running linux. I opened my home directory, did `fstatat` on an existing _ordinary_ file just fine (_without_ `AT_FDCWD`). Are you sure you're doing all the `#include` correctly? Mine, in order, were: `stdio.h stdlib.h unistd.h fcntl.h sys/stat.h`. From the PASE i, it looks like you've got some IBM concocted OS for the IBM i (nee AS/400)? And, PASE is a wrapper layer that allows [some] AIX compatibility? AFAICT, the reference for `AT_*` is linux. Is your file a symlink? `AT_FDCWD` is -100 and that turns on `AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW` (0x100)

Comment: From your post of the `#define AT_*`, they _are_ screwy. Under linux, they are (e.g.) 0x100, 0x200, 0400, 0x800, etc (i.e. real bit maps) in `fcntl.h`. So, maybe you've got either a wrong/dummy `.h` or there's a package that you need to install to get "real" definitions. Or, the symbols are defined to allow things to compile, but the runtime impl is a bit of a no-op.

Comment: It isn't remotely obvious that `AT_REMOVEDIR` would be used with `fstatat()`. Removing anything is not a read-only operation; the variants of `stat()` are all read-only functions. _[…time passeth…]_ Checking the POSIX specification, [`unlinkat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlinkat.html) uses `AT_REMOVEDIR` and [`faccessat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/faccessat.html) uses `AT_EACCESS`. Neither is for use with [`fstatat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstatat.html). Try using `0` for the flags.

Comment: Have you looked at `O_SEARCH` in the flags to `open()`?  The `fstatat()` manual mentions that.

Comment: On most Unix-like systems, `O_RDONLY` is 0 — not actually a bit that is set — so you `open()` the directory in read-only mode.  POSIX says there is a value, `O_SEARCH`, that can be used instead of `O_RDONLY`.  It didn't seem to make a difference on macOS Ventura 13.6.1 — it might matter on the system you're using.  What are the permissions on the directory you are working with?

Comment: What OS are you running? There is `OS/400` but the i (nee AS/400) also runs linux (since 2000?)? Now, clearly, the `.h` you're looking at isn't linux. So, again, this is some application layer to convert AIX compatible apps onto OS/400? Can you get _real_ linux on the box [possibly as a VM]?

Comment: @CraigEstey: It is definitely an IBM thing; that's why I posted the question... this code works on virtually every Unix and Linux system in the world. The file is not a symlink. I believe the `AT_*` definitions are correct–this is a port, not a direct implementation of the POSIX functionality. The OS is PASE subsystem on IBM i (OS/400) aka AIX compatibiblity.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I tried 0 for flags, along with pretty much every permutation of flags for `open()` – nothing helped. I did try `O_SEARCH`, and that one causes `open()` to fail with `EINVAL` so I don't even get to `fstatat()`. The directory permissions are `drwxr-sr-x` and I run the command as the user that owns the directory.

Comment: It increasingly sounds like a bug in the system you're using.  Have you got support for it?  If so, contact IBM for guidance.

Comment: My original theory was that there is a bug in the PASE implementation of this function; I was hoping by posting here it would gain more attention